# Relationship between angle (Stepper motor) and distance (Kinect)?

Tags: c#, kinect, distance, angle, kinect-sdk

Hi I am doing a project consisting of a stepper motor and Kinect. I want the stepper motor to rotate according to the distance of a body joint recognised by Kinect. I wan to cast a laser pointer on the left hand of a person all the time. If the person goes further away from the camera, the stepper motor moves in a way that the laser dot is at the hand.

Comment: Now we know what you want to achieve, what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to do it? hahaha Seriously I do not know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a copy of Visual Studio to develop in, Express should work:
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Then you need to get the Kinect development libraries:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/

Install both of those and run the test projects to get a feel for it. The learning curve will be pretty substantial if you've never developed before. Google is your friend, no one is going to be able to guide you step by step in this. You basic goal here is to find the distance the hand is at, and save it in a variable that can be used for other things(drive a motor).

Next, you'll need an easy way to drive your stepper motor. An arduino could work for this, but I don't know what voltage your motor is, so you may need external circuits to get the correct voltage to drive it.

You can interface with the arduino via the Serial port pretty easily:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473828/Arduino-Csharp-and-Serial-Interface

So a basic program flow would be:
Kinect > Save hand distance > Send X value to Arudino to make it move motor

For a seasoned programmer with extensive low voltage experience(ie me) this is a pretty easy task. If you've never done anything like this before, get ready to crack some books(Google)! There's a lot of things you'll need to learn to approach this properly, but it could be a fun project. Your combining quite a few disciplines here, so you'll need to know each one at least a little bit.